# cannot read property 'children' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have an `ul` which has certain `li`. I am looping through the `ul` and inside it through `li`. However I am getting an error :

```
let li = ul.children;
for (let index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
    while(li[index].children[0].checked)
    {
        ul.removeChild(li[index]);        
    }
}
```

When I replace the condition in the while loop with below the error disappears.

```
while(li[index] && li[index].children[0].checked)
```

I am not sure how adding the above line solved the error. Does it check if the `li` at that index exists? Like a null pointer check in JAVA?

Comment: Yes, like a null pointer check.

Comment: @Pointy, but there wont be any scenario where the list at that index doesn't exist because of the external for loop? Why do we need a check then

Comment: @ghostrider But you're *changing* the list in the loop.

Comment: You should be careful about removing elements from an array while iterating over it. `li[index]` might become `undefined` when you remove a child from `ul` since `li` and `ul.children` refer to the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you removed items from UL, UL's children Collection is changed.

You have three li, the second and the last one are checked.

Your loop will deleted the second one and now, you have only two items in your collection.

So, when you make the last loop, index = 2, but its out of bound. So li[2] doesn't exist anymore and is undefined.

And you'll never deleting the last checked item.